# XSLT add set value to a returned number variable

Tags: xml, xslt

This should be pretty simple, but after 3 hours of googling around, I apparently don't have the right wording to find the answer.

I have and XML return that I need to format for a page.  I have no control of the return as it is coming from UPS's databases.

I have it formatted fine, but now I need to increase the returned rate by $4.  This should be easy, but I'm very new to all of this and at a complete loss.

Here is the relevant portion of the returned XML:

```
<Response>
<ResponseStatusCode>1</ResponseStatusCode>
<ResponseStatusDescription>Success</ResponseStatusDescription></Response>
<RatedShipment>
    <Service><Code>03</Code></Service>
    <TotalCharges>
        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
        <MonetaryValue>21.17</MonetaryValue></TotalCharges>
    </RatedShipment>
</Response>
```

Here is the relevant portion of the XSL formatting:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<select name="shipping_options" id="shipping_options">
    <xsl:for-each select="/RatingServiceSelectionResponse/RatedShipment">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Service/Code = 01">
            <xsl:element name="option">
                <xsl:attribute name='value'>
                    1!!!
                    <xsl:value-of select="TotalCharges/MonetaryValue"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                UPS Next Day Air - $
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(TotalCharges/MonetaryValue, '###,###.00')"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</select>
```

Edit:
The format for the XSL is correct for other needs later.  The desired final output looks like this:

```
<select name="shipping_options" id="shipping_options">
    <option value="">Enter Zip Code To Update</option>
    <option value="1!!!77.49">UPS Next Day Air - $77.49</option>
    <option value="2!!!51.20">UPS 2nd Day Air - $51.20</option>
    <option value="3!!!22.73">UPS Ground - $22.73</option>
    <option value="4!!!38.01">UPS 3 Day Select - $38.01</option>
    <option value="5!!!71.02">UPS Next Day Air Saver - $71.02</option>
    <option value="6!!!108.01">UPS Next Day Air Early - $108.01</option>
    <option value="8!!!0.00">Please call for freight pricing - $0.00</option>
    <option value="9!!!0.00">Please call for international pricing - $0.00</option>
        </select>
```

Edit #2:
it was literally as easy as it should have been.  Just had to change this one bit to add "+4":

```
select="format-number(TotalCharges/MonetaryValue + 4, '###,###.00')"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like this :
(I modified your input XML, some of it was not proper.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <select name="shipping_options" id="shipping_options">
            <xsl:for-each select="Response/RatingServiceSelectionResponse/RatedShipment">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Service/Code = '01'">
                    <xsl:element name="option">
                        <xsl:attribute name="value">UPS Next Day Air - $</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(TotalCharges/MonetaryValue + 4, '###,###.00')"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </select>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehVZvvX

**Addition by Michael Kay**: the `xsl:for-each` instruction can be simplified to

```
<xsl:for-each select="Response/RatingServiceSelectionResponse/RatedShipment[Service/Code = '01']">
  <option value="UPS Next Day Air - ${format-number(TotalCharges/MonetaryValue + 4, '###,###.00')}"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Neither of those solutions work.
First, the format of my code is correct for the output that I need, I need s specific option value to feed back into a larger formula, but I need a friendly visable name for the drop down.  The 1!!! is actually a trigger in a regex snip used later. I will update OP with what the dropdown list looks like.
second, I cannot use a dynamic for-each loop like that because I need different names based off the service code type.  UPS only returns the code in the XML, and i need to translate that into a friendly name.
Finally, adding "+4" in the formula did not work.

Comment: that's a cool site! I've never used that before.  updated with the full code here:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehVZvvX/2

Comment: wait, it does work. -facepalm-
I was adding it only to the first option line in the XSL script , not realizing until playing around on your fancy website, that the order of the final output was the same!  It's been a long day.

the short answer, all I needed to do was to add "+ 4" like this: select="format-number(TotalCharges/MonetaryValue + 4, '###,###.00')"

Answer (score 1):

First some assumptions.

1. Your XML file has `<Response>` as root tag, but your XSL code refers to `/RatingServiceSelectionResponse`: I suppose this must be `/Response`.
2. The test `test="Service/Code = 01"` should be `test="Service/Code = '01'"` with quotes.
3. If you want to experiment, your XML file should contain the text `01` instead of `03` under the tag `<code>`. Otherwise, your code won't do anything.

In that case, you have to add 4 inside of the expression `format-number(TotalCharges/MonetaryValue + 4, '###,###.00')`

Meanwhile Sebastien answered exactly the same as I did...

Comment: Merci, votre réponse explique bien ce que j'avais aussi constaté!

Comment: This is only small snippets of much larger code, I only included the relevant parts for my question.  I simply want to increase the integer from the response by 4.  The format of the incoming XML is set by UPS and is nothing that I can change.

Comment: @Alith7:Yes, but your XSL code has to match the XML you receive.

Comment: the full code does.  the two small snips I grabbed happened to reference different shipment type codes, but ignore that part, all the rest of the code that I needed help with we correct.